# How to make each iteration unique in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to collection 1000 simulations, using R, over multiple sample sizes. The ultimate goal is to test the ability of mean, median, and geometric mean to return a known answer. First, I need to code 1000 simulations from a normal distribution of 5, 30, and 100 sample sizes. Currently, my code prints each iteration exactly the same. For example, in the for loop that prints 1000 iterations of a sample of 5, the same five numbers are printed 1000 times. How do I prevent this? I want each iteration to be unique Here is the code, with the general outline of the variables and for loops being identical for each sample size.

```
#Sample Size of 5
oneA <- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 1))
oneAVec <- c(oneA)
for (i in 1:1000){
  print(oneAVec)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are simply printing the variable you've already defined. If you want to have new random numbers with each loop, then generate them inside the loop.

```
for (i in 1:1000){
  print(round(rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 1)))
}

[1] 7 6 7 4 4
[1] 4 4 3 6 4
[1] 5 4 6 5 5
[1] 4 7 3 7 5
[1] 6 4 6 4 5
[1] 4 7 6 4 6
[1] 6 6 3 5 4
[1] 5 4 4 3 5
[1] 6 3 6 6 5
[1] 5 7 4 4 5
[1] 5 5 5 5 5
```